# Anonymous Login to Open fire With Strophe

Tags: openfire, strophe

I want to login to Openfire Server anonymously. I have tried with null username and password but not able to login. I have used Strophe on client side. Please Help me and give any suggestions. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

First of all from openfire admin panel add such property
**xmpp.auth.anonymous** true

Suppose your domain is test.com

```
var c = new Strophe.Connection("/http-bind/"); //if localhost
c.connect("test.com",null,function(constatus){
    console.log(constatus);
    if(constatus==5){//connected
        c.addHandler(function(message){console.log(message);}, null, "message", "chat");
        c.send($pres());
    }
});
```

that's all on client side!

I've implemented PacketInterceptor to see all packets

```
public void interceptPacket(Packet packet, Session session, boolean incoming, boolean         processed) throws PacketRejectedException {
    if(packet instanceof Presence){
        Presence presence = (Presence) packet;
                    log.info("Presence:"+presence.toXML());
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.setType(Type.chat);
        msg.setFrom("admin@test.com");
        msg.setBody("Hello from server");
        session.process(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: hope it helps other...because i didn't find any full solutions and spent 2-3 hours